# Log4j2: Can I alter logged events' log levels via configuration?

Tags: log4j2

I am using a 3rd party library whose source I do not have access to.  This library does a lot of logging at the ERROR level.  These ERROR-level log events it generates are interesting, but we do not consider them  to be error level events.

Rather than filtering these loud log events out from the log, I'd like to somehow have them be rewritten before they hit the appender to be logged at the INFO-level.

Is there any out-of-the-box way to configure log4j2 to change the log level of log events, or set a ceiling on the severity of a log event's log level?

I'd like this configuration to be specific to a class within the 3rd party jar and not all the classes in the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j 2 offers a standard way to accomplish this with the [Rewrite](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RewriteAppender) appender.

The `LoggerNameLevelRewritePolicy` allows you to replace certain log levels with another level for specific loggers.

Comment: This looks like it's it, I'll give it a try!  Thank you!